# Linq To Entities insert many to many but only unique values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have two Entities.  Article and Category.  Examples below:-

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateEdited { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

A many-to many relationship exists between the two so an ArticleCategory junction table also comes into play.  If I then create a new article object, say:-

```
var article1 = new Article{Content = "Article 1", Categories = new List<Categories>{new Category{Name = "Random Category"}}
```

and then I save this to the database and then I create another article object with exactly the same category name of 'Random Category', then my Category Table contains two entries for 'Random Category', when I only want unique category name values stored.  So my question is, using LINQ to Entities, how would I go about achieving this, especially keeping best practice in mind.  I assume I would compare against the category table using the Any operator but if a match is found, how do I then link the name correctly in the junction table to refer to the existing name.  I'v been trawling google but it's been amazingly hard to find any topic of value.  I have my own ideas how to deal with this but it's important I cut out the fluff and get straight to the nitty gritty so I can make sure I am doing it right first time.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying it.  Currently fiddling about as getting System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException : A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = FK_ArticleCategory_Categories_Category_Id ]

Comment: @Gert Arnold.  To use the attach method as detailed in the possible duplicate answer, I am required to provide the category primary key or I get the above error. However, the incoming category data only contains category name so the attach method will not work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a stored procedure which takes all the parameters and looks up the category by name on the SQL side. I assume you don't want to do that.

The only way I know to do this using EF is to acquire an instance of the Category entity and manually assign it. This will require two queries, one to get the entity and one to insert your new entity.

```
var category = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName) 
               ?? new Category { Name = categoryName };
var article = new Article 
              { 
                Content = content,
                Categories = { category }
              };
```